# Purpose of file with extension ^^^ in Pervasive SQL

Tags: sql, database, file-extension, pervasive

I'm researching a file extension "^^^".

Found the following info about this extension on FileInfo.com:

"Database file used by Pervasive.SQL database software; based on the Btrieve transactional database format; created by the database engine when the database is placed in Continuous Operations mode."

But it's not entirely clear what's the purpose of this file type. What exactly it contains? Is it a temporary copy of a database or something else that doesn't contain any actual data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those files are not temporary copies of the database or data files but they store the **changed** data during the time Continuous Operation is enabled.  It allows the changes made during that time to be rolled into the main data file after Continuous Operations is stopped.  Continuous Operations mode allows the main file to be copied or backed up in cases when the files are open (either because they can't be closed or just haven't been closed).